select index of a tensor by back propagation
Can the selected indexes of a tensor itself, but not the selected elements of indexes differentiable in PyTorch? Say the column index is obtained though a network, and the loss is computed based on the selected columns from the input x. So that I can select different indexes of the x by back propagation.
I searched several forums for answer for differential indexing. All answers it is by meaning the tensor of the selected indexes is differential, when all the tensor's grad of the unselected indexes are 0. However, my focus is whether the indexes itself is differential or not.

How would you get integer indices out of your network?

For 4D and 5D input, there is a way to sample output with differentiable index (which I think it do make the indexes differentiable) using torch.nn.functional.grid_sample. You can try if it fits your problem.

I may get integer indices from a network. Its input is my X(shape [1 : 30 : 256 : 256]), and output is indexes of one of my X's dimension, such as tensor with shape 10, and contains the indexes ranging from 0 to 29(take the second dimension of my input X as example). Next, I select my intact original X by my output indexes. However, the last index selection process is not differentiable.

Thx for torch.nn.functional.grid_sample, i will try it and reply later.

It seems that torch.nn.functional.grid_sample cannot change the num of channels. Therefore, it cannot be used for band selection.
